Spectral colors in filled wine glass
How to explain the stripes and dots of spectral colors in a wine glass that is filled by rosé?
Light source is the sun.


This is due to dispersion.
The refractive index of the glass (and of the wine) differs for the different wave lengths that are present in the white light of the sun. This is the same effect that allows you to see the spectrum of the sun with a prism.
The visible colour fringes are where the point of the image you see depends strongly on the refractive index. This is the case if the incident angle of the rays is close to 90° (or equivalently, the angle at which the rays exit the denser medium). The situation is of course complicated here, by the fact that the shape of the wine glass forms a (quite inaccurate, with different focal lengths at different points) lens – so the exact description of all visible features is a bit complicated (the process where color fringes appear in images projected by lenses is chromatic aberration).
The sharp line above the color fringes, where it goes from a bright image of the background to dark red, is where total reflection sets in (for rays reaching your eyes, and no transmitted rays can reach you from there).

Mentioning that there is dispersion is not sufficient to explain the origin of the specific pattern in the photo.

The "specific" pattern to me just looks like a magnification of the background fabric. The glass+wine worked like a lens.

(Plus distortion for parts of the image away from the center, where the lens is very far from a good lens – the bright rainbow stripes are just stretched version of the bright points in the pattern of the fabric – and there the chromatic aberration is also strongest.)

I think one way to look into this is to use other pictures to understand what is happening optically.
The picture you provide is, unfortunately, not that great because of a few factors:

The picture of the glass it at an angle. Therefore, it is not possible to know a few things about how the system behaves (which it may seem odd calling the glass "a system", but entertain me for a second here).
While the effect is very visible based on what Sebastian points out, it is interesting that a few additional angles can help to uncover what is happening.
From a ray optics perspective, it may be difficult without specific transformations.

That being said, I went around and first make the problem linear: Change the view of the wine glass to something more straightforward.

I start with a white wine for reasons that will be apparent: White wine is clear, and therefore, the background features can more easily be distinguished. I don't drink wine, therefore I have no idea, but I believe that each wine has a type of glass. To corroborate, I check the same picture with Rosé and the transformation looks the same, albeit "darker" because of the darker tint of the wine.

From a lens perspective, two things are immediately evident:

Where there is only glass, you can look through with some distortion. Therefore, the glass introduces a background barrel distortion.


This is because of the glass shape and also by having several small lenses that show that the straight grid in the background gets pushed outwards as the lenses go away from the center of the image.
Second, the lens formed by the wine and the glass is equivalent to a convex lens, because the image is inverted and demagnified (as it looks smaller than it is in real life) in both the sagittal plane (along the "Y" axis of the image if you may) and in the transversal plane (along the "X" axis of the image if you may):

With the aid of another wine, the sparkling, I will then make another change in the scene by elongating one of the axes (along the sagittal plane) like so:

With this information, it is possible to then make a few remarks about the picture you provide:

As Sebastian points out, the colors are due to dispersion of the refractive index of wine, therefore, you are seeing the effects of chromatic aberration. This means that the convex lens formed by the wine contained in the wine glass makes white light travel at different speeds due to the shape of the lens, the wavelength-dependent refractive index of wine (which is ethanol + water + glucose + trace other elements, as detailed here: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S030881462030947X and somewhat here: https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/je950188f but I think the problem here is that chemists use refractomers in the visible range usually, and therefore rarely provide spectral information about refractive index as their interest is different than, say, an optical scientist).



Next, the grid you see: As Sebastian points out, this is an image of the table cloth in the back. Here there is a remarkable difference between my examples and your table cloth, but it should be note that the distance between the back wall and the table cloth (in my examples and your picture) are different, and therefore, in your case because of the proximity of the grid you are seeing a magnification rather than a demagnification of the background. A quantitative amount I cannot really tell you and I don't feel like speculating too much.
The background is also distorted strongly along the sagittal axis and this is because from the perspective of the picture, I believe there is a sharp increase in height (as it would be for the flute glass for sparkling wine) causing the top small squares to be strongly distorted at the top.
The chromatic aberration seems to be point-like at each of the squares of the table cloth because effectively each of those points are emitting light which is then magnified by the wine-based lens, and chromatically aberrated by the dispersive effect (i.e. different refractive indices for each wavelength) of the wine.

Regarding why it seems that the colors are shifting from left-to-right at some point of the picture I think is because of a sudden change in the curvature of the glass with respect to where the camera is located, therefore it seems that the color of the rainbow suddenly shifts at some point, I have some theories on why that happens: a) I tested with a glass on my computer monitor and because I am constantly moving the water in the glass, then I see the color fringes from individual LCD dots moving around, because the water moves around. Either that or b) it is possible that actually, there is some effect of the lens being quite uneven (as the glass and the wine are not perfectly symmetric) as shown more or less nicely by these researches working on single-pixel imaging: https://www.mdpi.com/2304-6732/10/1/7

In general I think there are a lot of things going on, but it is very difficult to judge from such a picture. Other angles would have greatly helped, but I did my best to get some examples (thanks Virgin wines for having such nice, clear examples of wine lenses!) that would help to illustrate everything going on and try to make several leaps of logic to a somewhat reasonable conclusion.

This is not physics but speculation.

Can you explain what is unphysical about the explanation provided?

It seems like he made a pun here - speckle-ation... Anyway, nice introduction to what might happen in such a "system" :)
